# "location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission" even if I use runtime request permission

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, targetsdkversion

This is so weird. We  all know that if `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>` is set to 23+, you must ask for runtime permissions besides declaring `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in the manifest.

This has been working with no problem for years. Now, The problem is that when I am setting targetSdkVersion to "26", the LocationManager is not working anymore! and throws this error:

```
"gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
```

The only thing that I change in my app is the targetsdkversion from 23 to 26 and it breaks the app! Any ideas?

Comment: Have you declared the permission on manifest and requested the runtime permission?

Comment: @Ragesh Yes, that's why it is so weird

Comment: Can you please post your logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could fix the problem and I'll explain it here also in case someone else is facing a similar problem. I should add that while the problem is now fixed, it feels like a bug on Android or lack of documentation.

Because of some internal project reasons, I was requesting for the location permission like this:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(_activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
String[] requestedPermissions = null;
if (packageInfo != null)
{
    requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

    if (requestedPermissions.length > 0)
    {
        List<String> requestedPermissionsList = Arrays.asList(requestedPermissions);
        _requestedPermissionsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        _requestedPermissionsArrayList.addAll(requestedPermissionsList);
    }
}

for(int i=0; i < _requestedPermissionsArrayList.size(); i++)
{
    if(_requestedPermissionsArrayList.get(i).equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || // api level 1
            _requestedPermissionsArrayList.get(i).equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) // api level 1
        )
    {
        isFound = true;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_activity, new String[]{
                _requestedPermissionsArrayList.get(i)
        }, ExConsts.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        break;
    }
}
```

With this setup, the order of permissions in the manifest mattered! When I had:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

it didn't work but when I switched their order, it did work.

Finally, how did I fix the problem? like below, I mentioned both permission names

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_activity, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
}
```

Now, no matter the order of permissions in the manifest, it always worked fine. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this complete solution

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in `onCreate()` do this

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkAndroidVersion();
}
```

this method `checkAndroidVersion();`

```
public void checkAndroidVersion() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
                buildClient();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else
            {
            }

        } else {
            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                // Building the GoogleApi client
                buildClient();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            // write your logic here
        }

    }
```

this method `checkAndRequestPermissions()`

```
public boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

        int location = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (location != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Handle `onRequestPermission()` method

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("in main on request", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("in main on request", "location services permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                        buildClient();
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("in fragment on request", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                            showDialogOK("Location services  services are required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

declare this method `buildClient()`

```
public void buildClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
```

handle `onStop()`

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

declare this method  `checkPlayServices()`

```
/**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     */
    public boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

override the google api methods

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLocation == null) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        /**
         * This library works in release mode only with the same JKS key used for
         * your Previous Version
         */

    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(5000)
                .setFastestInterval(5000);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        try {
            if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
                buildClient();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        current_location = location;
        SharedPrefsUtils.setStringPreference(MainActivity.this, "user_current_latitude", current_location.getLatitude() + "");
        SharedPrefsUtils.setStringPreference(MainActivity.this, "user_current_longitude", current_location.getLongitude() + "");
        System.out.println("sjkbd jdsbj");
    }
```

> in the `Activity` or `fragment`

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
```